# Problems with creating instance of generic type

Tags: java, generics

I made a class `List <K extends Comparable<K>,V>` and I also have `class BST<T extends comparable<T>>`

so when I do something like

```
private List<String, String> st = new List<String, String>();
private static BST<Integer> tree = new BST<Integer>();
```

those work.

but this doesnt:

```
private static BST<List<String,String>> tree = new BST<List<String,String>>();
```

complains about not being within bounds.  what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

BST wants T to extend Comparable, and List doesnt extend Comparable, right

Comment: List extends the K value comparable

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter, `T` of class `BST` is expected to "extend" (actually, implement -- thank you generics!) `Comparable<T>`, but `List` doesn't satisfy that expectation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this.  What should I change the parameter of the BST class to? I've tried searching for examples, but only find very basic examples.

Comment: Your BST parameter looks fine. However, how do you expect to compare a List to another List?

Comment: I'm storing a key-value pair in a list. Each pair is inserted into the BST.  Each newly created pair will see if the key already exists, if it does, then the old pair will link to the new pair. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: BSTs dont store pairs; they store values. BSTs need to know whether A < B to know whether to send it to the left node or right node. From your declaration, you wants your BST to store Lists of items (and not individual items). So what does it mean for List A to be smaller than List B?

Comment: I want the BST to compare keys. These keys have a list associated with it.  Each key will have a list of values. I guess I'm unsure how to implement. For List A to be smaller than List B, List A's key should be smaller than List B's.